# Static member function and access operator

Tags: c++, lvalue, static-functions

I was just looking through lvalue(Value categories) from cppreference.com and came across [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) that specifies as :

In Built in Access operator of type E1.E2 :

> 3) if E2 is a static member function, the result is an lvalue designating that static member function. Essentially, E1 is evaluated and discarded in this case;

and For non-static member function :

> 4) if E2 is a non-static member function including a destructor, the result is a special kind of prvalue designating that non-static member function of E1 that can only be used as the left-hand operand of a member function call operator, and for no other purpose;

I have no idea of what this means, especially how Point no 3) is used as lvalue and for what purpose.
I know this is some detailed stuff which anyone rarely uses.. But out of curiosity, any help with any kind of example will be appreciated ::

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplified example from cppreference

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    int f() { return 10; }
    static int sf() { return 4; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a.f() << a.sf(); // A::sf() also works
}
```

Now, the part you quote states that `a.sf` is a lvalue, while `a.f` is not. What does that mean? It implies that you can take the address of `a.sf`:

```
auto fun = &(a.sf); 
fun();
```

while the same is not true for `a.f`:

```
auto fun = &(a.f);   // error 
// ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&A::f'
```

Comment: That doesn't explain much how call to static member function can work as lvalue as referenced in cppreference...

Comment: @Tilak_Chad so your question is specifically about the "... is an lvalue...". I think now I understand the question ;)

Comment: I think you want to call `fun` by `*fun()`.

Comment: @n314159 afaik both are fine

Answer (score 1):

You can for example take the address of a static member function and store it in a normal function pointer (so not a member function pointer):

```cpp
struct X {
    static void f(int);
    void g(int);
};

int main() {
    X x;
    void (*p)(int);
    p = &x.f; // works
    p = &x.g; // does not work
}
```

This makes also sense, since you can call `f` (only) without providing an object of type `X` while you can only call `g` when you provide such an object. Since you want to be able to call a function pointer by `*p(0)`, you cannot allow `&g` to be assigned to `p` while there is no problem with `&f`.

You can think of a public static member function roughly as a free friend function (not exactly but its closer to that than to a non-static member function) accessible through the struct/class.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
struct X{
    static void foo(){}

    void bar(){}
};

X makeX(){
  std::cout<<"make X called"<<std::endl;
  return X();
}

int main(){
  makeX().foo();
  makeX().bar();
}
```

In the call to `makeX().foo()`, `foo` is a `static` member function, so `makeX()` corresponds to `E1` in case 3): it is thus evaluated and discarded, so `makeX()` is called, but then the temporary `X` object is discarded and `foo` is called just as if you had typed `X::foo()`.

In the call to `makeX().bar()`, `bar` is a non-`static` member function, so `makeX()` is evaluated, and the temporary `X` object is used as the `this` parameter for the call to `bar`.